# Compress ranges of ranges of numbers in bash

Tags: bash, csv, range

I have a csv file named "ranges.csv", which contains:

```
start_range,stop_range  
9702220000,9702220999  
9702222000,9702222999  
9702223000,9702223999  
9750000000,9750000999  
9750001000,9750001999  
9750002000,9750002999
```

I am trying to combine the ranges where the stop_range=start_range-1 and output the result in another csv file named "ranges2.csv". So the output will be:

```
9702220000,9702220999  
9702222000,9702223999  
9750000000,9750002999
```

Moreover, I need to know how many ranges contains a compress range (example: for the new range `9750000000,9750002999` I need to know that before the compression there were 3 ranges). This information will help me to create a new csv file named "ranges3.csv" which should contain only the range with the most ranges inside it (the most comprehensive area):

```
    9750000000,9750002999
```

I was thinking about something like this:

```
if (stop_range = start_range-1)  
  new_stop_range = start_range-1
```

But I am not very smart and I am new to bash scripting.
I know how to output the results in another file but the function for what I need gives me headaches.

Comment: Welcome to SO,please do wrap your samples in CODE TAGS for clarity of question.

Comment: Don't use `bash` to process data. At the very least, use `awk`.

Comment: In this case, I suggest you to use `awk`.

Comment: First of all it doesn't matter what programming language or shell tool you will use but to understand your request. Is the input CSV always an ordered list, where the stop value of a line is always smaller than the start value of the next line? And in addition - is there never ever a stop value which overflows a start value? (e.g. 9702220000,9702224999 and next line 9702222100,9702222500)

Comment: @TomFreudenberg , the input CSV file is not always an ordered list. And yes, it can happen that a stop value overflows a start value as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your ranges are sorted, then this code gives you the merged ranges only:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     (FNR>1) && ($1!=e+1){print b,e; b=e="" }
     ($1==e+1){ e=$2; next }
     { b=$1; e=$2 }
     END { print b,e }' file
```

Below you get the same but with the range count:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     (FNR>1) && ($1!=e+1){print b,e,c; b=e=c="" }
     ($1==e+1){ e=$2; c++; next }
     { b=$1; e=$2; c=1 }
     END { print b,e,c }' file
```

If you want the largest one, you can sort on the third column. I don't want to make a rule to give the range with the most counts, as there might be multiple.

If you really only want all the ranges with the maximum merge:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     (FNR>1) && ($1!=e+1){ 
        a[c] = a[c] (a[c]?ORS:"") b OFS e
        m=(c>m?c:m)
        b=e=c=""
     }
     ($1==e+1){ e=$2; c++; next }
     { b=$1; e=$2; c=1 }
     END { a[c] = a[c] (a[c]?ORS:"") b OFS e
           m=(c>m?c:m)
           print a[m]
     }' file
```

Comment: You are half way: you still have to count the ranges and to print the one with the most ranges merged.

Comment: @PierreFrançois a mild update has been added. The question is a bit unclear

Comment: @kvantour , Yes, you are right, I don't want only all the ranges with the maximum merge. Sorry for my bad explaining. Your first approach is what I need. However, the input file can have "bad input ranges" like that : 9750002000,9750002999
9702220000,9702220999
9750000000,9750000999
9702222000,9702222999
9702223000,9702223999
9750001000,9750001999
9750002000,9750001999
9750002000,9750000999
9750002000,9750009999
9750007000,9750007999
9750008000,9750008999
9750009000,9750009999 , so 2 equal start_ranges with different stop_ranges

Comment: @kvantour ,  or the case when the last 3 ranges in the file : 9750007000,9750007999 9750008000,9750008999 9750009000,9750009999  are already imbricated in the range 9750002000,9750009999. Another case is when the stop_range is greater than a start_range (e.g.: 9750002000,9750000999 ).

Comment: Could you please update your question and clearly state what you want? Expected input, expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
  BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","}
  NR == 2 {
    start = $1; stop = $2; i = 1
  }
  NR > 2 {
    if ($1 == (stop + 1)) {
      i++; 
      stop = $2
    } else {
      if (++i > max) {
        maxr = start "," stop;
        max = i
      }  
      start = $1
      i = 0
    }
    stop = $2
  }
  END { 
    if (++i > max) {
      maxr =  start "," stop;
    }
    print maxr
  }
' ranges.csv
```

Comment: How do you handle multiple cases with the same `max`?

Comment: We shoud ask the OP.

Comment: @kvantour , when it happens to have multiple cases with the same max, we should take into account the max which have the most numbers in these ranges (e.g.: if a new max range is 9702222000,9702222999 and another new max range is 9702222000,9709999999 we should take into account the second one (the biggest interval) because it has more numbers).

Comment: @PierreFrançois , i tried to use your approach. I used an unsorted input file named "inputRanges.csv". I wrote a script with the command sort -t "," -k 1 -n inputRanges.csv > ranges.csv    at the beginning + your awk. It doesn't work as expected. The input file looks like:  start_range,stop_range  
9750002000,9750002999  
9702220000,9702220999  
9750000000,9750000999  
9702222000,9702222999  
9702223000,9702223999  
9750001000,9750001999  
9750002000,9750001999  
9750002000,9750000999  
9750002000,9750009999  
9750007000,9750007999  
9750008000,9750008999  
9750009000,9750009999

Comment: I didn't foresee the case of an unsorted list.

Comment: @PierreFrançois , yes, and that's way i made that sort. But the result is 9750000000,9750000999